# how can I overwrite an object in matlab?

Tags: java, matlab, oop

I have a loop in which I want to create an object. it must share the same name for each loop. like

```
for i=1:100
car=car(args(i))
%in this loop do stuff with car
end
```

the problem is that at the second iteration matlab tries to access the element car(args(i)) instead of calling the costructor of the class car.

this is the error for arg=SS

```
Error using subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'SS'.
```

In java I'd simply call the ''new'' parameter, like

```
 car=new car(args);
 //do stuff with the car istance
 car= new car(args);
 //do stuff with the new car istance
```

I can't allocate an array of ''car'' since each istance is several hundreds of megabytes. I tried looking for a keyword similar to new in matlab but I had no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling your variable the same name as your class. The first time you define `car=car();`, `car` starts to refer to an instance, rather than the class, and subsequent calls to `car()` will not call the class constructor, but will try to access an index of your object `car` (as if it were an array, hence the error about `subsindex`).

You always have to be careful in MATLAB *not* to shadow built-in function names, or in this case, a class name. In Java, arrays are accessed with square brackets (I guess?), so there's no ambiguity.

So, just don't use `car` as the name of an instance of class `car`. Call it `mycar=car(args(i))` instead.

Comment: thank you, now that you said so it's evident... bad programming habbits never die, I'll pick this as the best answer for future reference, thanks again.

Comment: It's never too late to start:) MATLAB programming *is* very different than using lower-level languages such as C++ or Java. Many subtleties like this are not evident at first. For instance, you could easily call a partial sum variable `sum` in JAVA, but that would again shadow the `sum()` built-in in MATLAB. And `i`, `j` refer to the imaginary unit, which can lead to minor confusion. I prefer `k`-`l`-`m`-`n` as loop variables, others like `ii`, `jj` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the car instance from work space in the end of each iteration:

```
clear car
```

Comment: this indeed works, thanks for this hotfix! I'll leave this open a bit to see if there's a more standard way to do it. thanks again,some times simple solutions are the best.